# Request query string values are not accessible in ASP.NET WebForms postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a URL like so:

> http://localhost:3878/Admin/Residential/ResidentialPlacementEdit.aspx?ResidentialPlacementID=1&YouthID=6&GroupID=7&ReferralID=7

Now the ReferralID parameter is accessible via `Request("ReferralID")` - but only before a postback. After a postback for some reason it is coming back as `Nothing`. Why is this? How can I get the query string parameters after a postback?

I am initializing a variable like so:

```
Private Sub SetupPage()
    ...
    If Request("ReferralID") = "" Then
        referralID = "0"
    Else
        referralID = Replace(Request("ReferralID"), ";", "")
    End If
    ...
End Sub

Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init
    ...
    SetupPage
End Sub
```

And referralID is coming back as zero even if it is set in the query string, but only after a postback - on initial page load the value is getting set properly. In fact Page_Init and Page_Load are not being called on a postback at all!

Here is the submit button, in case it matters:

```
<input name="ResidentialPlacementSave" type="submit" class="ctbutton" value="Save" onclick="validateForm('StartDate','Intake Date','R');return document.MM_returnValue">
```

I tried adding `runat="server"` to the submit button but that didn't seem to help...

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. On a side note, there is no need to use `Page_Init` normally. Not even with dynamic controls.

Comment: Oh, it would help to call `SetupPage` before the code that is looking for the variables it initializes, silly me...